# Building a cache for heavily-used data?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, caching

If I have a list of objects that are shared between all users of a Java EE application, it is useful to introduce some kind of cache, or `@ApplicationScoped` pool that holds those objects?

I could image that if eg 100 Users go to an overview page and list all of these objects: where should these objects come from? A fetch from DB for every of these users, or a shared datapool "on the fly"?

At least if they are in some kind of shared ServiceManager, there will also be like 100 getObjects() request to this manager. Would this have any advantage to many db fetches?

I have no experience in this and need some advise.

Comment: If you're concerned about performance you can take a look at JBoss infinispan that can be configured to work as a L2 cache for JPA or like a regular cache for your own (non ORM related) objects.

Comment: Take a look at http://ehcache.org/

Answer (score -1):

Create a singleton class which contains all these objects. if these objects are null, then fetch it from db and initialize it. If its not null return the current value to all users..